# Is traditional JavaScript image pre-loading taboo

Tags: css, javascript, layout

I remember the good-old-days (not really) back when I was still sucking the teet of Dreamweaver to build websites and the lure of playing copypasta with fancy built-in scripts (ex, image-swap) was like black magic.

I'm pretty far removed from that now days but I was adapting a small site from it's original FrontPage (::cringe::) format to a standard HTML/CSS implementation and couldn't help wondering... should I should re-implement the JavaScript image pre-loading into the current version? Or, is there a better way?

I don't want to block the page from loading by requiring the user to request all the assets withing the page by using the traditional JavaScript pre-loader method. I value giving the user something to look at ASAP, and there's some potential harm to my Google mojo by doing so.

Is there a cleaner solution to prevent unnecessary page-reflows during loading? Such as, setting the static width/height dimensions through a CSS style attribute on the image element.

Comment: Please avoid mixing 2 or more questions. Some people just want to answer to one and it makes it confusing to the readers. Besides how will you accept the best answer?

Comment: @Osvaldo I don't see the problem, both are related and not mutually exclusive. I tend to say too much in my questions so here's the simple version. Is pre-loading images through javascript still standard practice in web development; If not, is there a viable CSS alternative?

Comment: @EvanPlaice - You don't see the problem because you're not the one answering the question. Besides, you might get more question upvotes if you split up questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying image dimensions in HTML and/or CSS has *always* been recommended since the days of HTML 2.0, and eliminates the need for page reflows due to delayed image loading.

That takes care of static images.  The other case is images that won't show up until *after* the page has loaded.

For simple things like rollover effects, you should be using background images and the CSS `:hover` selector, <s>which AFAIK will be preloaded in most modern browsers</s>.  Or, better yet, use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), which guarantee preloading and speed up image loading in general.

For more advanced things like [image sliders](http://designmodo.com/jquery-image-sliders/), you do need some JavaScript.  For those, when possible, I'd recommend using an existing script that will take care of preloading and other technical details in an efficient and well tested way.

Comment: Nice. I have been using :hover and sprites all along but it's interesting that JS image pre-loading can still be made useful for non-static content. Does that hold true for all images that the user 'may' see (ex full size image after clicking on thumbnail). It has been a while since I've done a site from scratch, and 'best practices' have evolved.

Comment: background-images only referenced in the `:hover` pseudo-class won't be preloaded by the browser. But as you say, "CSS sprites" will 'preload' the image, simply because it is the _same_ image that is used in the _unhovered_ state and displayed when the page first loads.

Comment: @w3d: Hmm, you seem to be right.  I just ran a quick test, and it does seem that at least Firefox 11 does not preload images only referenced in `:hover`.  I stand somewhat surprised, but corrected.

Comment: @w3d Interesting. If that's the case, I guess I'll have to update my navigation sprite to include both states.

Answer (score 5):

Preloading images used in other pages can be done without interrupting current page loading. You can load the extra images after all the assets from the current page have finish loading.

Use the window.onload JavaScript event *(or the $(window).load event if you use jQuery)* to start loading the images needed to render the next page.

Comment: I think you mean $(document.ready) not $(window).load. $(window).load fires after the whole page and all included images have been successfully loaded (ie, event is fired too late in the execution chain). See http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/.

Comment: I understood you wanted to preload images to be used in other pages/ajax calls, so loading them is faster. And in that case $(window).load is the right answer because you just want the browser to cache them.